# table chaos since upgrade to 4.8

Tags: table

Changes (via text editor) to existing html tables (in pages/posts) appear correctly in visual editor and when tested directly in browser.
but when saved and viewed from front end offer haywire results: columns disappeared, text from under the table appearing IN the table... some of the text in cells not appearing.

Other changes to same pages/posts work correctly. Only when I touch a table is there a problem.

Wordpress.org forums suggests: don't use tables (!?),  problem with new version of TinyMCE (what can I do about this?)

Here's the defective page:

https://tangoforge.com/gravity-landing/studioberlin/

The table in question starts with the word 'monthly' about 3/4 of the way down the page. it ought to have 4 columns.

https://pastebin.com/Cv4DQtHA

I pasted the same code on a regular wp page in case something to do with gravity-landing was screwing it up: (see comment for link)

Same result at first. Then in desperation (as this is a very important page in my site) I did something I don't normally do, which is to modify the table in the VISUAL editor.... this is where things started to get *really* wierd:

I messed around trying to copy and paste the information. i *copied* column 2 "flex plan" content and pasted it into column 1. suddenly column 2 became visible front-end, correctly (but the redundant content miraculously does not display in column 1).

i tried this trick with column 3, and then column 2 disappeared again. so rolled back to revision.

then I pasted column 3's content as regular text *below* the table with its own h6 section heading and no table formatting. when i did this, it didn't appear, but the FAQ jumped up INTO column 4. (despite having never been formatted as part of the table.   i rolled back the miracle revision again.

and yes, when i did any cut and paste i switched to text editor to make sure everything was located correctly in the html. the FAQ was definitely never inside the  tags!

see comment for link to html in pastebin.

advice (other than "turn off all your plugins and use some other theme") would be very appreciated.

So... what MIGHT cause corruption in table formatting without causing other kinds of corruption ???

Thank you!

Comment: page:  http://www.tangoforge.com/studioberlin
html: https://pastebin.com/juvwREGu

Comment: When we say turn off plugins and use another theme, the aim isn't to fix the problem but to figure out which plugin is causing it by a process of elimination. That way you can turn everything back on except the bit that's causing the issue, and start working on that to fix the root problem. Otherwise you have an open ended investigation where anything could be the culprit

Comment: Also, we tend to have a 1 question per question rule, afterall you can click the ask question link multiple times and just mention by URL that they're related. Right now someone who knows the answer to Part 2 can't answer because their answer has to cover both parts

Comment: Part II is not a separate question. It's further information on what I tried to do.

Comment: Your HTML on that page is broken with mismatching tags. There is no point in even guessing if there might be anything wrong on wordpress side (most likely not) in this case. You know what you should do.... disable plugins, switch to one of the core theme... if the table works, the problem is with whatever generates the other html on that page

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for your response, but I'm confused. I checked to make sure the html I wrote did not have any problems, and I have put it in pastebin to show that. As far as I know it does not have any mismatching tags. If you are saying that it's broken when the table is viewed from the browser, this I know. the question is why is wp 4.8 breaking tables?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up, I did some more research on what causes html corruption, and one possible answer is different versions of jquery being called by different plugins. So i installed "jQuery Updater".

This didn't fix it, but it gave me the clue to toggle on/off plugins that use jquery. When I hit the 3rd of my very many plugins, I found the one which was causing the problem.

This is a much better strategy than "TURN OFF ALL PLUGINS" and change your THEME because it's must less disruptive to user experience and does not run the risk of losing plugin settings.